# select one array out of multiples API spits out

Tags: php, arrays

I never encountered something similar:

I'm using an API that is spitting out exactly this text 
(I'm using `print_r($content)` where content is the result form API)

```
Request:
Array
(
    [0] => GET
    [1] => https://api.xxx.com/api/v1/xxx
    [2] => Array
        (
        )

    [3] => 
)

Request:
Array
(
    [0] => GET
    [1] => https://api.xxx.com/api/v1/xxx
    [2] => Array
        (
        )

    [3] => 
)
Array
(
    [symbol] =>  XXX
    [timestamp] => 1514994289069
    [datetime] => 2018-01-03T15:44:49.069+00:00
etc...
```

how to I get the third array? 
`$content[2]` clearly doesn't do the desired output...

Comment: This looks like output from a loop, not from a single array. Is each of these `Request:` items a single API call? A normal single `print_r()` wouldn't have this structure.

Comment: How do you print the 3rd array? clearly the `Request:` messages are not coming from from `print_r`, so you have 3 single calls to `print_r` possibly.